# command line : ignore particular file while using wildcards

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal

Consider I have lots of shell scripts in a folder named `test`. I want to execute all the files in it except one particular file. what do I do? relocating the file or executing the file one after an other manually is not an option. Is there any way I could do this in single line. Or perhaps, adding something to `sh path/to/test/*.sh`, which executes all files?

Comment: Do you mean I want to include all the files except one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for file in test/*; do
    [ "$file" != "test/do-not-run.sh" ] && sh "$file"
done
```

If you are using `bash`, you can use extended patterns to skip the undesired script:

```
shopt -s extglob
for file in test/!(do-not-run).sh; do
    sh "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for FILE in `ls "$YOURPATH"` ; do 
  test "$FILE" != "do-not-run.sh" && sh "$YOURPATH/$FILE"; 
done
```

Comment: Parsing the output of `ls` would fail if there were any paths containing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

`find path/to/test -name "*.sh" \! -name $pattern_for_unwanted_scripts -exec {} \;`

Find will recursively execute all entries in the directory which end in .sh (-name "*.sh") and don't match the unwanted pattern (\! -name $pattern_for_unwanted_scripts).

Answer (score 0):

in `bash`, provided you do `shopt -s extglob` you can use "extended globbing" allowing to use `!(pattern-list)` which matches anything except one of the given patterns.

In your case:

```
shopt -s extglob
for f in !(do-not-run.sh); do if [ "${f##*.}" == "sh" ]; then sh $f; fi; done
```

Comment: That will match every file that isn't "do-not-run.sh".

Comment: Or, just move the extension out of the negative pattern: `!(do-not-run).sh` matches all "*.sh" files except "do-not-run.sh"